# string key with co-responding right next integer value

Tags: java

I am new to java. I am working on a particular problem where routing and account number is given I have to find for routing and account number as string key with co-responding right next integer value (Key- value pair )

On whatever page it will finds routing and account number it will return it anyways with co-responding right next integer value

```
    String aRegex = "account"; 
    String rRegex = "routing"; 

    Pattern aPattern = Pattern.compile(aRegex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher aMatcher = aPattern.matcher(text);
    Pattern aPattern = Pattern.compile(rRegex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher aMatcher = aPattern.matcher(text);

    if (aMatcher.find() && rMatcher.find()) {
    //Add to a map
        

    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to find zip or phone number in PDF.");
    }
    //i want a map which can get  routing and account number as string key with co-responding right next integer value
```

Comment: Not quite clear what the question is. Also we need to see an example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find matching numerical values that are preceded by a label, you can try something like the following:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Bank {
    private static final Pattern accountPattern;
    private static final Pattern routingPattern;

    static {
        accountPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=account\\D{0,10})(\\d+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        routingPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=routing\\D{0,10})(\\d+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pdfText = "...\n account: 12345 ...\n routing: 1122334455 ...\n ...";
        Map<String, Long> accountInfo = extractAccountInfo(pdfText);

        System.out.println(accountInfo);
    }

    public static Map<String, Long> extractAccountInfo(String text) {
        Map<String, Long> result = new HashMap<>();
        Matcher accountMatcher = accountPattern.matcher(text);
        Matcher routingMatcher = routingPattern.matcher(text);

        if (accountMatcher.find() && routingMatcher.find()) {
            result.put("account", Long.parseLong(accountMatcher.group()));
            result.put("routing", Long.parseLong(routingMatcher.group()));
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

### Output

```
{routing=1122334455, account=12345}
```